# Django 1.8 Form action CBV returns HTTP Method not allowed

Tags: django, forms, http-status-code-405

My intention is calling a function defined inside a form when submitting the form button. In a previous setup the code worked fine, but now I'm receiving a HTTP 405, Method not allowed error. The CBV-Form is not directly implemented on the site, because I have multiple forms defined. So I'm accessing it via the action form method. This was also used in the previous setup.

Here is the form implemented in the view:

```
    <form class="form-group" action="{% url 'MetaZabbix:UpdateAllMaintenance' %}" method="post">
    <div class="col-lg-8">
        Letzte Aktualisierung am {{ last_update|date:"d.m.Y" }} um {{ last_update|time:"H:i" }} Uhr.
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-1">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="refresh_maintenances">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span> Daten aktualisieren
        </button>
    </div>
    {% csrf_token %}
</form>
```

The form itself:

```py
class UpdateAllMaintenancesForm(forms.Form):

    def updateMaintenances(self):
        """Update maintenances for all active Zabbixs

        Currently we will ignore all exceptions which will raise during updating process.

        """
        do_something_great()
```

The view:

```py
class UpdateAllMaintenances(FormView):

    form_class = UpdateAllMaintenancesForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('MetaZabbix:MetaZbxMaintenances')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        print('hello')
        form.updateMaintenances()
        return super(UpdateAllMaintenances, self).form_valid(form)
```

And at last the url:

```py
from django.conf.urls import *
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

from metazbx.views.maintenance import \
    MetaZabbixHomeView, \
    MetaZabbixMaintenanceView, \
    MetaZabbixMaintenanceDetailView, \
    MaintenanceDelete, \
    MaintenanceUpdate, \
    UpdateAllMaintenances
from metazbx.views.zbxhostconf import \
    ZbxHostConfListView, \
    ZbxHostConfDetailView, \
    ZbxHostConfCreate, \
    ZbxHostConfDelete
from metazbx.views.zbxhostjreq import \
    ZbxHostJReqListView, \
    ZbxHostJReqDetailView, \
    ZbxJReqTypeCreate, \
    ZbxJReqTypeDelete, \
    ZbxJReqTypeUpdate


urlpatterns = patterns('metazbx.views',
                       url(r'^$', MetaZabbixHomeView.as_view(), name='MetaZbxHome'),
                       url(r'^listzbxjreq/$', login_required(ZbxHostJReqListView.as_view()), name='ListZbxJReq'),
                       url(r'^listzbxconf/$', login_required(ZbxHostConfListView.as_view()), name='ListZbxConf'),
                       url(r'^detailzbxjreq/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', login_required(ZbxHostJReqDetailView.as_view()),
                           name='DetailZbxJReq'),
                       url(r'^detailzbxconf/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', login_required(ZbxHostConfDetailView.as_view()),
                           name='DetailZbxConf'),
                       url(r'^createzbxconf/$', login_required(ZbxHostConfCreate.as_view()), name='CreateZbxConf'),
                       url(r'^createzbxjsreq/$', login_required(ZbxJReqTypeCreate.as_view()), name='CreateZbxJReq'),
                       url(r'^updatezbxjsreq/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', login_required(ZbxJReqTypeUpdate.as_view()),
                           name='UpdateZbxJReq'),
                       url(r'^deletezbxjsreq/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', login_required(ZbxJReqTypeDelete.as_view()),
                           name='DeleteZbxJReq'),
                       url(r'^deletezbxconf/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', login_required(ZbxHostConfDelete.as_view()),
                           name='DeleteZbxConf'),
                       url(r'^deletemaintenance/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', login_required(MaintenanceDelete.as_view()),
                           name='DeleteMaintenance'),
                       url(r'^maintenances/', login_required(MetaZabbixMaintenanceView.as_view()),
                           name='MetaZbxMaintenances'),
                       url(r'^maintenance/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', login_required(MetaZabbixMaintenanceDetailView.as_view()),
                           name='DetailMaintenance'),
                       url(r'^updatemaintenance/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', login_required(MaintenanceUpdate.as_view()),
                           name='UpdateMaintenance'),
                       url(r'^maintenances/updateallmaintenances', login_required(UpdateAllMaintenances.as_view()),
                           name='UpdateAllMaintenance'),
                       )
```

Comment: Do you have duplicate url name? Posting your complete urls.py will be helpful.

Comment: What I have seen, I think not, but I have edited my post.

Comment: The `UpdateAllMaintenance` url looks malformed (`r'^maintenances/updateallmaintenances'` instead of `r'^maintenances/updateallmaintenances/$'`)